# Perl fork(), exec() and then kill creating zombie process

Tags: perl, fork

I am trying to launch android emulator in perl using fork, exec. Afterwards I need to kill it too but killing it results in zombie processes with emulator running in background.

I've tried killing using `kill -1` as well as `kill -9` and `killall -v emulator`. I've also tried exec'ing by appending explicit exec("exec command ...") but either way I get a zombie process till the perl script is running.

Here is my code:

```
my $CMD;
my $PID;

sub waitkey()
{
    local( $| ) = ( 1 );
    print "Press <Enter> or <Return> to continue: ";
    my $resp = <STDIN>;
}


$|++;

$CMD = "emulator -avd audit -no-snapshot-save";
# $CMD = "exec emulator -avd audit -no-snapshot-save";

$PID = fork();
if ($PID==0) 
{
    print "forked!\n\n";
    sleep(1);
    exec("$CMD");
    die "Unable to execute";
}

print "PID: $PID\n\n";

sleep(1);
print "------ Processes before killing -----\n";
print `ps aux | grep emulator`;
print "------ Press a key to kill -----\n\n"

&waitkey;
# `kill -1 $PID`;
`kill -9 $PID`;

print "------ Processes after killing -----\n";
sleep(1);
print `ps aux | grep emulator`;


print "----- waiting ... -----\n";
#-- do somehing here with assumption that emulator has been killed --
&waitkey;
```

In the output I see

```
------ Processes before killing -----
qureshi  10561  0.0  0.0   3556   980 pts/5    S+   13:28   0:00 emulator -avd audit -no-snapshot-save
qureshi  10562  0.0  0.0   4396   616 pts/5    S+   13:28   0:00 sh -c ps aux | grep emulator
qureshi  10564  0.0  0.0  13580   928 pts/5    S+   13:28   0:00 grep emulator
```

and after killing the process

```
------ Processes after killing -----
qureshi  10561 30.0  0.0      0     0 pts/5    R+   13:28   0:01 [emulator64-arm]
qureshi  10619  0.0  0.0   4396   612 pts/5    S+   13:28   0:00 sh -c ps aux | grep emulator
qureshi  10621  0.0  0.0  13580   932 pts/5    S+   13:28   0:00 grep emulator
```

How do I get rid of the Zombie process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `waitpid` in parent process after killing the child process. That's because you use `fork` to get a new process, Perl wouldn't do the clean-up job for you as in `system`.
But I recommend [a better module](http://search.cpan.org/~bzajac/Proc-Background-1.10/lib/Proc/Background.pm) in CPAN which does the whole messy thing, I find it very convenient.

Answer (score 5):

A zombie is just a process table entry that's waiting for the parent process to come by and collect its exit status.  As documented in [perldoc fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html),

> If you fork without ever waiting on your children, you will accumulate
>   zombies. On some systems, you can avoid this by setting $SIG{CHLD} to
>   "IGNORE" .

Setting `$SIG{CHLD}` works on most unix-type systems, including Linux, so that would be the easiest way to arrange for your children to rest in peace.

BTW, calling user-defined functions with the `&` prefix is a Perl 4-ism.  In current Perl versions, you should use just `waitkey` or `waitkey()` instead of `&waitkey`.